# Finding te number of AVL trees of height N

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, tree

The definition of an AVL tree I have is:

"The balancing factor for vertex x in a binary search tree T is the difference between the height of x's left subtree and right subtree.

A binary tree T is called an AVL tree if the balancing factor of each of its vectors is either 0, -1,  or 1."

I need to find a regresive function for calculating the number of AVL trees of height N. I know the solution is:

```
V[i] = V[i-1]^2 + 2V[i-1]*V[i-2]

V[0] = 1
V[1] = 3
V[2] = 15
```

Can someone please explain? I am completely lost.

Comment: Write down a suitable recursive definition of the AVL tree. "An AVL tree of height 0 is empty; an AVL tree of height `i` is a node with two AVL trees as children, such that their heights are ... or ... or ..." (fill in the blanks).

Comment: I added a definition, hope it clears things up, sorry

Comment: I know where to find the usual definition. You need to *rewrite* the definition so that it is explicitly *recursive*, and then look at it and analyze it and perhaps find a similarity between this recursive definition and the formula you have. I have provided you with a template of the recursive definition.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself thanks to n.m.'s comments.

The answer is as follows:
v[i] = v[i-1]v[i-1] + v[i-1]v[i-2] + v[i-2]v[i-1]

Where the first component is where both subtrees are of the same height (0), the second one is where there left tree is of a bigger height (1) and the third one is where the right tree is of the bigger height (-1).